# Linux RHEL - Find disk type

Tags: linux, hard-drive, rhel

I have Oracle Linux Server release 5.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6) and I want to check if the disk type is SATA, SCSI, ATA or SAS or any other disk type.

I installed lshw (hardware lister) and executing "lshw -class storage" gives the below output

```
   description: SCSI storage controller
   product: 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI
   vendor: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic
   physical id: 10
   bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
   logical name: scsi0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: scsi bus_master rom scsi-host
   configuration: driver=mptspi latency=64 maxlatency=255 mingnt=6
   resources: irq:17 ioport:1400(size=256) memory:d8820000-d883ffff memory:d8800000-d881ffff memory:84008000-8400bfff(prefetchable)
```

Does this mean this is a SCSI disk type? 
How do you find out if the disk type is SAS?

Thanks!